# JSON marshaller ignored when rendering object with child objects

Tags: json, grails, grails3

Currently running grails 3.2.10

Given the following domains

```
class Form {
  List<Step> steps
  static hasMany = [steps:Step]
}

class Step {
  Form form
  static belongsTo = [Form]
  String docID
  String stepRef
}
```

When trying to view the JSON representation of the form `render Form as JSON`, the list of Steps is rendered as a list of IDs, e.g., `"steps":[{"id":15},{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]`

Ok, so I set up a JSON marshaller and registered it in BootStrap:  `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(new StepMarshaller())`

The StepMarshaller just renders the the important fields.  When I call this directly, it works just fine:

```
render Step.get(1) as JSON
```

yields the correct JSON (`{"docID":"The_ID","stepRef":"1"}`)

However, rendering the parent Form as JSON still returns the list of IDs (the default behavior).  What am I missing that's causing the Marshaller to be ignored for child objects?

Comment: What about deep converter ? JSON.use('deep'){
            render (form as JSON)
        }

Comment: That does seem to do the trick, add this as an answer so I can mark it.  For me, this ended up being too deep...  there are other associations on the object which provide WAY too much so I ended up just writing a custom Marshaller form Form for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use default deep json converter:

```
JSON.use('deep'){ 
   render (form as JSON) 
}
```